# Pgfplots, put decorative arrow center at the specified position

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows, text-decorations

I would like to draw an arrow at the vertical part of a parametric curve. Consider, for example, the following trochoida.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta
  , bending
  , decorations.markings
  }
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width           = 0.4\textwidth
      , height          = 0.25\textwidth
      , axis equal
      , axis lines      = middle
      , enlargelimits   = false
      , tick style      = {draw = none}
      , ymin            = {0.0}
      , xtick           = \empty
      , ytick           = \empty
      ]
        \addplot+[
            no markers
          , thick
          , domain =  -2.08869:8.37188
          , smooth
          , postaction = {decorate}
          , decoration = {
                markings
              , mark = at position 0.132010 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
              , mark = at position 0.210413 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
              }
          ] ({x - 1.5 * sin(x r)}, {1.5 - 1.5 * cos(x r)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I calculated the correspondent integrals and know that positions of the "vertical" parts of the curve are 0.132 and 0.210 expressed as a fraction of the overall length. The result looks ugly, because this is where the very tips of the arrows are placed:

[image]

How to put the center of the arrow at these points, not its tipping end?

Also a side question: I specified "bend", but it doesn't look bending at all. Why?

Comment: Uhm how do you want the arrows to appear? Can you include a handmade sketch of your desired result? Thank you.

Comment: I want the arrows be located where x derivative is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you define explicitely the length of the `\arrow` markings. You could use a `decoration tranform`, see `pgfmanual` §24.4.1.
In the present case I shifted the arrows by their half-length.

Here is the output, with in blue your plot and the sifted one in seli-transparent red.

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta
  , bending
  , decorations.markings
  }
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width           = 0.4\textwidth
            , height          = 0.25\textwidth
            , axis equal
            , axis lines      = middle
            , enlargelimits   = false
            , tick style      = {draw = none}
            , ymin            = {0.0}
            , xtick           = \empty
            , ytick           = \empty
        ]
        \addplot+[
            no markers
            , thick
            , domain =  -2.08869:8.37188
            , smooth
            , trig format=rad
            , postaction = {decorate}
            , decoration = {
                    markings
                    , mark = at position 0.132010 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
                    , mark = at position 0.210413 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
                }
        ] ({x - 1.5 * sin(x)}, {1.5 - 1.5 * cos(x)});
        \addplot+[
            no markers
            , thick,opacity=0.5
            , domain =  -2.08869:8.37188
            , smooth
            , trig format=rad
            , postaction = {decorate}
            , decoration = {
                    markings
                    , transform={xshift=1mm}
                    , mark = at position 0.132010 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
                    , mark = at position 0.210413 with {\arrow{Stealth[length = 2mm, bend]}}
                }
        ] ({x - 1.5 * sin(x)}, {1.5 - 1.5 * cos(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit puzzling. `xshift` shifts along the curve? Tikz integrates to find the length along the curve?

Comment: @facetus. No, the decoration is moved according to the local tangent to the curve, computed at the original marking coordinate, so this trick doesn't work anymore if you use large shifts.

Comment: I see. Nothing's ever easy.